# Is there an R function to fit an ARIMAX model for all possible combinations of my exogenous variables?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, combinations, arima

I am trying to fit an ARIMAX model to describe & forecast the development of a population size time series using 7 different exogenous variables time series (migration, birth rate, life expectancy ...).
With the following code you get the results for an ARIMAX model with migration as the exogenous variable:

```
auto.arima(population, xreg=migration)
```

Its also possible to get the results for an ARIMAX model using all the exogenous variables:

```
reg_matrix<-cbind(migration,LEmale0,LEfemale0,LEmale65,LEfemale65,birthage,birthrate)
auto.arima(population, xreg=reg_matrix)
```

I want to get the results for an ARIMAX model for all the possible combinations of exogenous variables. Obviously I could do the described steps for all the possible combinations. But since there are 7 exogenous variables and therefore 5040 different possibilities (7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1) it would take ages and I can't believe there is no faster way to do this.

I am new to R so I would really appreciate the help! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with `auto.arima` and you didn't provide sufficient example of your data to work through completely, but this may help.  **Assuming variable order doesn't matter** (likely in arima).  The number of unique combination is *only* 127.  You can produce a list of them to feed to `auto.arima` one by one with the following

```r
library(DescTools)
library(purrr)

variables <- c("migration", "LEmale0", "LEfemale0", "LEmale65", "LEfemale65", "birthage", "birthrate")

combo_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(variables)) {
   combo_list[[i]] <- DescTools::CombSet(variables, i, 
                                         repl = FALSE, 
                                         ord = FALSE, 
                                         as.list = TRUE)
}

combo_list <- purrr::flatten(combo_list)
length(combo_list)
#> [1] 127

# various points in the list

combo_list[[1]]
#> [1] "migration"
combo_list[[34]]
#> [1] "migration" "LEfemale0" "LEmale65"
combo_list[[127]]
#> [1] "migration"  "LEmale0"    "LEfemale0"  "LEmale65"   "LEfemale65"
#> [6] "birthage"   "birthrate"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're right in the point of having just 127 unique combinations as the variable order doesn't matter! After creating the list as recommended in your answer I have the following problem which is the reason why I still can't run all the calculations automatically: The variable names are stored as "strings" in the list, but I need them to be stores as the variables. Because otherwise I can't feed them too auto.arima as the following error message occurs: error in auto.arima(population, xreg = combo_list[1]) : 
  xreg should be a numeric matrix or a numeric vector

Comment: Could you please share `dput(head(population, 30))` and `dput(head(migration, 30))`

Answer (score 0):

If you created the names for the all possible combination as in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63862591/13929705), you can try this code.
I used the `dplyr` package to work with a dataframe (pipe operator `%>%` and `select`). You must use {{}} to link the names of the selected columns, then change into a matrix. All your results you can save into a **list object**.

**The data is in the mydf.**

```
library(DescTools)
library(purrr)

variables <- c("migration", "LEmale0", "LEfemale0", "LEmale65", "LEfemale65", "birthage", "birthrate")

combo_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(variables)) {
   combo_list[[i]] <- DescTools::CombSet(variables, i, 
                                         repl = FALSE, 
                                         ord = FALSE, 
                                         as.list = TRUE)
}

combo_list <- purrr::flatten(combo_list)

###################################################################################
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

mod <- list()

for (j in 1 : length (combo_list){ 
for (i in mydf %>% select(combo_list[[j]]) %>% colnames) {
  message("Working with ",i)
  mod[[i]] <- auto.arima(mydf$population, xreg=mydf %>% select({{i}}) %>% as.matrix)
  }}
```